# pubsub emulator v331: SLF4J error on start, no logging

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm getting this error when starting the pubsub emulator (version 331):

```
[pubsub] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
[pubsub] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[pubsub] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I'm running on Debian testing, with `openjdk-11-{jre,jdk}:amd64` version `11.0.11+4-1`.

I tried installing packages: `libslf4j-java` and `liblog4j1.2-java` but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working with `log4j` by the following method, which is probably not ideal:

Install log4j and slf4j:

```
apt install liblog4j1.2-java libslf4j-java
```

Rebuild the `cloud-pubsub-emulator` jar to include the contents of `slf4j-log4j12.jar` and log4j-1.2.jar, using this script:

```
#!/bin/sh -ev

cd $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/platform/pubsub-emulator/lib || 
cd /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/pubsub-emulator/lib ||
{
        echo >&2 cannot find pubsub-emulator
        exit 1
}

if [ ! -e cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar.orig ]; then
        mv -i cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar.orig
fi

mkdir jar
cd jar
jar xf /usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar
jar xf /usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar
jar xf ../cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar.orig

jar -c -m META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -f ../cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar .

rm -rf jar
```

Apply this patch to `google-cloud-sdk/platform/pubsub-emulator/bin/cloud-pubsub-emulator`:

```
--- cloud-pubsub-emulator.orig  2021-03-15 10:34:16.708333078 +1100
+++ cloud-pubsub-emulator.fixed 2021-03-15 14:02:57.629491322 +1100
@@ -64,7 +64,7 @@
     ;;
 esac
 
-CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar
+JARPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.4.0.jar
 
 # Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
 if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
@@ -112,7 +112,7 @@
 # For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
 if $cygwin ; then
     APP_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$APP_HOME"`
-    CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
+    JARPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$JARPATH"`
     JAVACMD=`cygpath --unix "$JAVACMD"`
 
     # We build the pattern for arguments to be converted via cygpath
@@ -168,4 +168,4 @@
   cd "$(dirname "$0")"
 fi
 
-eval \"$JAVACMD\" $JVM_OPTS -jar \"$CLASSPATH\" $APP_ARGS
\ No newline at end of file
+eval \"$JAVACMD\" $JVM_OPTS -cp \"$CLASSPATH:$JARPATH\" com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.Main $APP_ARGS
\ No newline at end of file
```

Create a file `log4j.properties` in the project directory where we will run the emulator:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Finally, I set `CLASSPATH="."`, to include the current directory with the `log4j.properties` file. We could also use an absolute path:

```
export CLASSPATH="."
```

It's now possible to run the emulator and see the logs:

```
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start
```

Comment: This is now using `cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.8.0.jar` I updated your script and it works